# Casting at runtime

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have read several posts related to my question but none address my particular issue.

The class below holds some info that is going to get passed info a Razor engine for parsing.

```
public class ActionResult
{
    public object ViewModel { get; set; }
    public string View { get; set; }
}
```

The ActionResult.ViewModel property would hold an instance of a view model class that could be of any custom type that my view requires as my views are strongly typed.

I'll new up the razor engine.

```
var razorEngine = new RazorEngine(razorScriptFile, _moduleResult.ModuleContext, "");
```

then call a render method, it's signature is...

```
public void Render<T>(TextWriter writer, T model){}
```

The challenge I have is that I am not sure on how to call this render method using the info within the actionResult instance available at runtime.

if I hard code the method call it work fine...

```
razorEngine.Render<MyViewModelType>(writer, actionResult.ViewModel);
```

but i guess what I should be doing is getting the actionResult.ViewModel as MyViewModelType or just casting it to MyViewModelType. But I am not sure how to call the razorEngine.Render() method while providing it's Type at runtime.

using .Net 4.5

Edit...

I guess what i thought I could do is..

```
Type type = actionResult.ViewModel.GetType();
var model = actionResult.ViewModel as type;
```

but this does not work

Comment: You need to use reflection, or just pass Object.

Comment: Is anything wrong with razorEngine.Render(writer, (MyViewModelType)actionResult.ViewModel)? I'm not sure I understand what the difficulty is.

Comment: When calling the render method on the razor engine the model param needs to be of the same type as what the razor view is typed to. i guess my shortcoming is how to cast the model from object type to the needed custom type (MyViewModel) at runtime.

Comment: @SLaks I was just passing the model as an Object but something internally within the RazorEngine does not like that and my parsed razor view's model ends up being null. The RazorEngine class is in a library that is part of another dll that I cannot modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection to achieve what you need:

```
var viewModel = actionResult.ViewModel;
var method = typeof (RazorEngine).GetMethod("Render").
    MakeGenericMethod(viewModel.GetType());
method.Invoke(razorEngine, new[] {writer, viewModel});
```

But as the comments rightfully stated, why can't you cast `viewModel` to your desired type?

EDIT: Since the only other overload for `Render` is the non-generic `Render(TextWriter)` you can use the following code:

```
var method = typeof (RazorEngine).GetMethods().
    Single(m => m.Name == "Render" && m.ContainsGenericParameters).
    MakeGenericMethod(viewModel.GetType());
```

However I suggest you to make your code safer by adding additional checks. If in a new version `Render` gets a new overload with generic parameters, the above code will throw an exception. You can use `First` instead of `Single` but that could create bugs in your code if, as said above, the library gets an update.

Comment: I agree, why can't I? the desired type is determined at runtime, so what is the syntax or expression to do this correctly?

Comment: If the actual type of `viewModel` is determined (from your original question I thought that you just wanted to pass its pre-determined type to the generic method) at runtime, then the method offered in my question will work for you.

Comment: So I have to use Reflection to get this going?

Comment: @JBeckton Yes, you might also want to cache your results or encapsulate them somehow so you don't have to use large amounts of Reflection code.

Comment: The Reflection is a bit tricky, I keep getting an error "Ambiguous match found." because I have two Render methods on that class.

Comment: @JBeckton I've added an example adapted to your needs.